# Can we use "I have with me"

Tags: british-english

`I will give all the boxes I have with me`

Is this grammatically correct to use "I have with me"?

Comment: The "with me" bit could be redundant here. You could change it to "I'll give you all the boxes I have" and mostly mean the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question simply: yes.

Saying "with me" may be redundant if all the boxes you have are with you, but if there are boxes you have that are *not* with you and you are trying to say you will give the boxes that **are** with you, you would **need to** include the "with me" part.